# Do I need a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, datatables, partition

I have three tables - `T1`,`T2` & `T3`.

For each row in `T1` I need to fetch the all the data from that table and a few other columns from a third table `T3` and insert into `T2` //Which is partitioned version of `T1`

Do I need stored procedure for this?

Comment: How is the data being added? Is it a single row at a time, or is it a bulk upload of many rows? How is data inserted into T1 currently? Directly from Java/some other non-database code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't , it can be done with a simple insert as select:

```
INSERT INTO T2
SELECT t1.*,t3.col1,t3.col2...
FROM T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3
 ON(t1.ID? = t3.ID?)
```

Of course you have to change this query to whatever columns you want, and the join condition to the relations between the tables.

Comment: Thanks.. that helps a bit, have some issues here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36008450/select-each-row-and-insert-into-another-table

Comment: Whilst you can do this using just SQL, I personally would code a stored procedure to handle the inserts into both T1 and T2. That way, should some other application come along that needs to do the same thing, you have a reusable module, and you don't have to replicate the logic in your other application.