# Select each row and insert into another table

Tags: oracle, select, join, foreach, insert

At a first glance, this is my query

```
 INSERT INTO T2 
 SELECT T1.*,  T3.DATETIME, T3.STATEID
 FROM T1 WHERE T3.DATETIME BETWEEN '01-NOV-15' AND SYSDATE
 LEFT OUTER JOIN T3
 ON (T1.DOCID =  T3.DOCID);
```

`T1` AND `T2` are almost identicle in terms of number of columns; only `T2` has two columns extra (CREATIONDATE, STATEID)

Each and every row of `T1` needs to be inserted in `T2` + the two additional columns `CREATIONDATE & STATEID` which are only available in `T3`. Both `T1` and 'T3' share the `DOCID` which could be used to join them...

Some issues remain, help is much appreciated..

Getting Error

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Comment: Can you please better explain the question? Are you having an error or an unexpected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in in the position of the `WHERE` clause, which has to come after the list of joined table:

```
INSERT INTO T2 
 SELECT T1.*,  T3.DATETIME, T3.STATEID
 FROM T1 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN T3
   ON (T1.DOCID =  T3.DOCID)
WHERE T3.DATETIME BETWEEN '01-NOV-15' AND SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect, where comes after the join:

```
 INSERT INTO T2 
 SELECT T1.*,  T3.DATETIME, T3.STATEID
 FROM T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T3
ON (T1.DOCID =  T3.DOCID)
WHERE T3.DATETIME BETWEEN '01-NOV-15' AND SYSDATE
```

Comment: Hah yea, by 10 seconds:) No problem.

Comment: Would you be able to answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035397/sql-error-ora-14300-while-partitioning-and-subpartitioning